# Ruby script to max out CPU?

Tags: ruby, load, cpu, cpu-usage

I am trying to write a script to utilize a CPU heavily. (I need this to load test a service running on multiple hosts.)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: (Why) does it have to be in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something like `yes > /dev/null` on the command line.